# How to do actions when MongoDB Realm Web SDK change stream closes or times out?

Tags: mongodb, realm

I want to delete all of a user's inserts in a collection when they stop watching a change stream from a React client. I'm using the Realm Web SDK for this.

Here's a summary of my code with what I want to do at the end of it:

```
import * as Realm from "realm-web";

const realmApp: Realm.App = new Realm.App({ id: realmAppId });
const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
const user: Realm.User = await realmApp.logIn(credentials);

const mongodb = realmApp?.currentUser?.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
const users = mongodb?.db("users").collection("users");

const changeStream = users.watch();

for await (const change of changeStream) {
  switch (change.operationType) {
    case "insert": {
      ...
      break;
    }
    case ...
  }
}

// This pseudo-code shows what I want to do
changeStream.on("close", () => // delete all user's inserts)

changeStream.on("timeout", () => // delete all user's inserts)

changeStream.on("user closes app thus also closing stream", () => ... )
```

Realm Web SDK patterns seem rather different from the [NodeJS ones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) and do not seem to include a method for closing a stream or for running a callback when it closes. In any case, they don't fit my use case.

These MongoDB Realm Web [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/mongodb) lead to more [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/js/latest/Realm.MongoDBCollection.html#watch) about Realm. Unless I'm missing it, both sets don't talk about how to monitor for closing and timing out of a change stream watcher instantiated from the [Realm Web SDK](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/quickstart/), and how to do something when it happens.

I thought another way to do this would be in Realm's Triggers. But it doesn't seem likely from their [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/trigger-types/).

Can this even be done from a front end client? Is there a way to do this on MongoDB itself in a "serverless" way?

Comment: Out of curiosity - could you share a few more details about the use-case?

Comment: @oblivion02 I'm collecting users' GPS coordinates so I can send them unimportant data from other people in their immediate vicinity. But I don't need to keep any of it so I want to delete it when they close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the inserts specifically when a (client-)listener of a change-stream stops listening you have to implement some logic on client side. There is currently no way to get notified of such even within Mongodb Realm.

Sice a watcher could be closed because the app / browser is closed I would recommend against running the deletion logic on your client. Instead notify a server (or call a Mongodb Realm function / http endpoint) to make the deletions.

You can use the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) to reliably send a request to trigger the delete, even when the window unloads.

```js
Client side

const inserts = [];
for await (const change of changeStream) {
  switch (change.operationType) {
    case 'insert': inserts.push(change);
  }
}
// This point is only reached if the generator returns / stream closes
navigator.sendBeacon('url/to/endpoint', JSON.stringify(inserts));

// Might also add a handler to catch users closing the app.
window.addEventListener('unload', sendBeacon);
```

Note that the `unload` event is not reliable [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event). But there are some alternatives which maybe be good enough for your use case.

Inside a [realm function](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/#reference-documentation) you could delete the documents.

That being said, maybe there is a better way to do what you want to achieve. Is it really the timeout of the change stream listener that has to trigger the delete or some other userevent?

Comment: I couldn't get the Beacon API and the "unload" event to work in this case due to various constraints including that the MongoDB HTTPS endpoints require headers, I think. `sendBeacon` failed but `curl` worked with headers. So I think you're right. I'll have to use a server. Maybe I'll just run a daily cron job. Thanks!

Comment: Http endpoints require you to add the client domain under 'allowed origins' in the App Settings. Yes this is a CORS thing.